# How do I set the origin to an object's face on a Mac?

Tags: origin, osx

I've just started learning Blender and I'm following an online course where the teacher is using a Windows computer, but I have a Mac.

Some commands are easy to "translate" but whenever I try to set the origin to a face by selecting the face > <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+*right click* I get this. The new face appears wherever I click on the screen.

What's weird is that when the origin is not even near the object and I use the same hotkey, no matter where I click on the screen, the origin does move to the center of the object, but it doesn't work with faces. I've tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+*right click*, <kbd>Option</kbd>+*right click*, and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+*right click*, but none of them work.

I'm using the 2.93.5 version for now since it's the one used in the tutorial. I'm using a regular mouse, not the trackpad or the magic mouse.

So far the only solution I've found is to set the 3D cursor to the selected face, then set the origin to the 3D cursor and send the 3D cursor back to world origin but I'm looking for a quicker way to do it.

[image: My object after I try to place the origin on the face facing us]

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what is happening in that tutorial. When I use Ctrl + right-click somewhere, I extrude the selected face (or edge or vertex) to the point where I'm clicking. I'm using Windows as well, but I cannot set the origin to a selected face with this shortcut. Maybe it would be best to tell exactly what is done in the tutorial or name the tutorial and the timestamp where this happens so we can try to investigate what's going on there.

Comment: ...or do you mean placing the 3D cursor instead of the origin? But that's Shift + right-click. If you want to find out how this works in your Blender, go to _Preferences > Keymap_ and enter "set 3d cursor" in the search field. Then you get a list of all the shortcuts for this function in the different editors.